# What is the right way to write sentences in the format "someone for something (a role/position)"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

I see that it is very common to see phrases like:

1. X for President
2. Y for Governor

However, to me, these don't sound right. I mean, when I see similar phrases, I notice a difference. Eg: "Recommended X for captaincy". If this example is correct, why not use the former ones like this?

1. X for presidentship/presidency.
2. Y for governorship

Why is it not right to use "recommended X for captain"? What is the actual difference? What is the grammatically correct way?

Answer (score 1):

*X for President* is a standard structure used to support candidate X, who is in an election for President. It means, "I want X to be the President". If you say, "X for presidency", it means, "I want X to be the presidency", which is wrong.

The phrase, "Recommended X for captaincy" isn't a sentence, and doesn't have any idiomatic meaning, so it's not correct. It could be correct as part of the sentence, "***I** recommended X for captaincy*", but there, it's a sentence about something I did in the past, rather than a declaration of support for a current candidate in a future election.

Further, it *is* correct to say, "I recommended X for captain", and it means "*I recommended X for **the position of captain***, which is the same thing as "the captaincy".

Answer (score 1):

Both there phrases are short for **Vote for X in the forthcoming election.** or some similar phrase encouraging the reader to cast their vote for a particular candidate.
They have been abbreviated to make then quicker and easier to read or write. They also fit easily on placards where one may only get a glimpse of the content. Their full meaning is understood as they have been used many times. They may not sound right to a non native English speaker, but have become common usage at election times.